# Does ubuntu have a social client faster than Gwibber?

Tags: software-recommendation, facebook, twitter

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 and I began using Gwibber for my accounts of twitter and facebook, but it's so slow.

Answer (score 5):

There are several Twitter clients other than [Gwibber](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gwibber/) available in the Software Center : [Choqok](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/choqok/), [Turpial](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/turpial/), [Pino](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pino/) and [Hotot](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hotot/). There is also [Polly](https://launchpad.net/polly).

If I had to make a "top 5", it would be, from the best to the worst (not tested Pino) :

1. [Hotot](http://hotot.org) (fast and the most complete).
2. Polly (nice and promising client). It is formerly known as "Schizobird".
3. Choqok (a little worse than Polly).
4. Gwibber (too much basic).
5. Turpial (one of the worst Twitter clients I have ever seen).

But the best thing to do is testing them all and making your own opinion about this.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be interested in [Choqok](http://choqok.gnufolks.org/).

```
sudo apt-get install choqok
```